# Count the most frequent values in a row pandas and make a column with that most frequent value

Tags: python, pandas, frequency

I have a data frame like this below:

```
     a  b  c
0    3  3  3
1    3  3  3
2    3  3  3
3    3  3  3
4    2  3  2
5    3  3  3
6    1  2  1
7    2  3  2
8    0  0  0
9    0  1  0
```

I want to count frequency of each row and add a column result containing the max frequency like this below:

```
     a  b  c result
0    3  3  3  3
1    3  3  3  3
2    3  3  3  3
3    3  3  3  3
4    2  3  2  2
5    3  3  3  3
6    1  2  1  1
7    2  3  2  2
8    0  0  0  0
9    0  1  0  0
```

I tries to do transpose and looping through the transposed columns to get the value_counts but could not got the right result.
Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.mode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mode.html) with select first column by positions with [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df['result'] = df.mode(axis=1).iloc[:, 0]
print (df)
   a  b  c  result
0  3  3  3       3
1  3  3  3       3
2  3  3  3       3
3  3  3  3       3
4  2  3  2       2
5  3  3  3       3
6  1  2  1       1
7  2  3  2       2
8  0  0  0       0
9  0  1  0       0
```

Comment: I got here 1 min late . :)

Comment: Thanks for the prompt results. I will apply it to my larger df.